# Average Disk Sec/Transfer

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon

I imported a perfmon CSV into the [Pal tool](http://pal.codeplex.com/) and it formulated the ugly csv into something very readable. [image: Pal Output]. However I'm unable to identify the amount of IOPS that's being reported. I'm not sure, but looking at the Avg Disk Sec/Transfer it's showing my average at 0.019. Does anyone know how to convert this into the # of IOPs being (ie 100, 500, 1000 iops)?

Comment: Avg. Disk sec/Transfer measures latency.  You want to measure Disk Transfer/Sec for IOPS calculations.

Comment: Floyd, put that as the answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avg. Disk sec/Transfer measures latency. You want to measure Disk Transfer/Sec for IOPS calculations.  Also make sure when you do your analysis with PAL you take note if the disks are RAID virtual disks containing more than one physical disk etc.  Otherwise you can get invalid threshold/results.